# Kotest: PythagTriple example failing with erroneous function call

Tags: maven, kotest

I am using IntelliJ and Maven, have downloaded the Kotest plugin, and I have added the dependencies to pom.xml (kotest-runner-junit5-jvm, kotest-assertions-core-jvm, kotest-property-jvm, all version 5.5.0).

The following basic example is working:

```
class MyFirstTestClass : FunSpec({
    test("my first test") {
        1 + 2 shouldBe 3
    }
})
```

But I cannot make another example work, the PythagTriple:

```
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FunSpec
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.StringSpec
import io.kotest.data.forAll
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

data class PythagoreanTriple(
    val a: Int,
    val b: Int,
    val c: Int
)

class MyTests : FunSpec({
    context("Pythagorean triples tests") {
        forAll(
            PythagoreanTriple(3, 4, 5),
            PythagoreanTriple(6, 8, 10),
            PythagoreanTriple(8, 15, 17),
            PythagoreanTriple(7, 24, 25)
        ) { (a, b, c) ->
            isPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c) shouldBe true
        }
    }
})

fun isPythagoreanTriple(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Boolean = a * a + b * b == c * c
```

I could find two variants of this example, one using forAll, the other using withData. Both do not work.

There seem to be two problems:

(1)

```
Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public suspend fun <A> forAll(vararg rows: Row1<TypeVariable(A)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B> forAll(vararg rows: Row2<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B, C> forAll(vararg rows: Row3<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B, C, D> forAll(vararg rows: Row4<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B, C, D, E> forAll(vararg rows: Row5<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B, C, D, E, F> forAll(vararg rows: Row6<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B, C, D, E, F, G> forAll(vararg rows: Row7<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F), TypeVariable(G)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F), TypeVariable(G)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H> forAll(vararg rows: Row8<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F), TypeVariable(G), TypeVariable(H)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F), TypeVariable(G), TypeVariable(H)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
public suspend fun <A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I> forAll(vararg rows: Row9<TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F), TypeVariable(G), TypeVariable(H), TypeVariable(I)>, testfn: suspend (TypeVariable(A), TypeVariable(B), TypeVariable(C), TypeVariable(D), TypeVariable(E), TypeVariable(F), TypeVariable(G), TypeVariable(H), TypeVariable(I)) -> Unit): Unit defined in io.kotest.data
```

Using withData just leads to Unresolved reference: withData, and I haven't found an import.

(2)

```
Kotlin: Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
```

This seems to refer to the following:

```
        { **(a, b, c)** ->
            isPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c) shouldBe true
        }
```

These must be some basic problems I was unable to solve, given I am a newbie. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 mistakes making your test not work:

1. Your test setup does not contain a test, but only a context. This can simply be solved by changing the `context` into a `test`.
2. You should not use your own data type for the `forAll`-rows, but as the message in (1) suggests, the different variants of `forAll` are defined for data types `Row1`, `Row2`, `Row3`, and so on. Each of them can be created with `row(...)`. (There is one `row` function for each arity from 1 to 14.)
3. The variants of `forEach` do *not* specify a function with one `RowX` parameter, but a function with `X` parameters of types that are the parameter types of `RowX`. Therefore, it is not correct that the parameters `a, b, c` are surrounded by parentheses - which is a notation for destructuring one parameter into its components.

Altogether your test works when you change it in the following way:

```
class PythagoreanTripleTest : FunSpec({
    test("Pythagorean triples tests") {
        forAll(
            row(3, 4, 5),
            row(6, 8, 10),
            row(8, 15, 17),
            row(7, 24, 25)
        ) { a, b, c ->
            isPythagoreanTriple(a, b, c) shouldBe true
        }
    }
})
```